# Clarification in bash script

Tags: bash, unix

I have a bash script which I think is making a false assumption.

The bash script is as shown:

```
running()
{
if
    test -e .pid
then
    pid=`cat .pid`
    if
        ps -p $pid | grep -q $pid
    then
        return 0
    fi
fi
return 1
}

dd=`date +'%d'`
if
    running
then
    echo Still running PID: 
    cat .pid
else
    echo $$ > .pid
    echo Current PID: $$
    java -cp ./runLoad2.jar:$CLASSPATH runLoad.mainClass
fi
```

In my opinion the above bash shell script is making a false assumption while checking if the process id is still active or not.

Here while starting for the first time there is no .pid file so it creates the file and stores the pid in the .pid file.

The second time on wards it checks if the process id stored in the .pid file is active or not and if it is inactive or if the ps commad does not return any input it starts the java program.

But here after the first load is complete the pid is released back to os and when the shell script runs for the second time it uses the old pid which can be used by some other process and this is where I think its making a false assumption thinking that the stored process id always refers to this shell script.

I'm not sure if I'm correct. Can someone clarify.

Comment: $$ will get the process id of the current running process. I hope you are trying to monitor the java process and not the bash script. If so then you have to get the process id after you have started the java process and push the same to .pid file

Comment: @Ragjuram: How can I grab the pid of the java program, is it by using exec command of bash script.

Answer (score 1):

In the last `else` clause, you need to clean up after the java program finishes by deleting the .pid file:

```
else
    echo $$ > .pid
    echo Current PID: $$
    java -cp ./runLoad2.jar:$CLASSPATH runLoad.mainClass
    rm -f .pid
fi
```

Otherwise, as you surmise, the pid may be reused.

The above assumes that the java process does not fork or otherwise spawn background processes.  If it does, you have other issues.

If there is a chance that your process terminates by ctrl-C or some such signal, then you need to trap the signal and put the clean up code in the trap.  To do that, put the following near the beginning of the script:

```
MyExit() {
    rm -f .pid
    exit
}
trap MyExit EXIT
```

This causes the bash function MyExit to run when the script receives an EXIT signal.

**MORE:** Your program, modified minimally to add the exit trap, would be:

```
MyExit() {
    rm -f .pid
    exit
}

running()
{
if
    test -e .pid
then
    pid=`cat .pid`
    if
        ps -p $pid | grep -q $pid
    then
        return 0
    fi
fi
return 1
}

dd=`date +'%d'`
if
    running
then
    echo Still running PID: 
    cat .pid
else
    trap MyExit EXIT
    echo $$ > .pid
    echo Current PID: $$
    java -cp ./runLoad2.jar:$CLASSPATH runLoad.mainClass
fi
```

The definition of the MyExit function could go a variety of places as long as it is defined before the trap statement is executed.  I put it at the top because it is commonly considered good style to have bash function definitions at the top.

The trap statement should to be placed strategically after the decision has been made to write the `.pid` file and before it has been written.

Comment: Where do I place `trap MyExit EXIT` in the bash script.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your java command may be internally `fork`ing & the parent among the 2 processes may be exiting, keeping the child running in the background.
   Hence the bash script exits, & PID becomes available to OS.
2. Also, on another note, I would recommend adding `exec` before the java command, because (most likely,) you would want to monitor the java process rather than the parent (bash wrapper).
   By adding `exec` bash script PID will be inherited by the java process.

To verify speculation (1), try the exec method I described in (2). Check in `ps -ef` output, it the java process has indeed spawn a child process. If the parent process has exited, the child process should have ppid=1 (init)

Comment: If I run the java class as : `exec java -cp ./runLoad2.jar:$CLASSPATH runLoad.mainClass`, will the bash script wait for the java program to complete its execution.

Comment: Your bash script will be replaced by the java program. Check how [`exec`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec) works... (Link is about the C exec function. But you should get sufficient clues with this manual...)